# HP Proliant Server with Red Hat Linux Enterprise 5

Tags: linux

I have a question. How can I check a user who did access to the Server let say 2-3 days before? I am trying to investigate on who was the person who has gained access to the particular server via remote. Can I catch the IP Address who did access to the server as well? Thanks.

Comment: via remote what? as in via regular Linux means (SSH for instance) or via the iLO hardware? there's a huge difference, and if it's via linux means then please edit the hardware model out of the question as it's wouldn't be relevant at that point.

Answer (score 1):

The `last` command might prove helpful. It displays a list of users logged in since /var/log/wtmp was created.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get what you want from:

lastlog -u user -b 2

Cheers